# Elasticsearch Query with non english characters

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

This is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "*value",
        "name",
        "*text"
      ],
      "query": "LYNGSGÅRD"
    }
  }
}
```

The value is indexed in the field "valueText" as "text" using defaults. Nothing extra.

When I run this in Kibana Devtools as is, it works. In the inspect mode, Kibana is escaping the Å before it goes to the backend.

In my case, I'm invoking the REST API of Elastic from my code.
The query gets printed correctly when I print it. This query when copied, runs from Kibana dev tools. The characters are not garbled.

But when running from code, elasticsearch doesn't bring back any results.

I'm not sure if there's something I need to add as an extra mapping/setting in the field or or an issue with the way I send the query to elastic.

Answer (score 0):

I try add a analyzer with [filter asciifolding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html) .

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "filter": ["asciifolding"], 
  "text": [
    "LYNGSGÅRD"
  ]
}
```

Token

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "LYNGSGARD",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```